# Datetime in javascript, is it a bug?

Tags: javascript

Hello all javascript guru,

I've came across this javascript code that struggled me abit to understand why it didn't work as expected. So thought i post it here seeking for your help.

Basically the code is to convert a Date to milliseconds format and that milliseconds value then be converted back to Date object again but when comparing, they are NOT equal?

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentTimeInMill = Date.parse(currentTime);
var currentTime2 = new Date(currentTimeInMill);

// debug in firefox
console.log(currentTime);
// Date {Thu Jul 07 2011 09:56:19 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)}

console.log(currentTime2);
// Date {Thu Jul 07 2011 09:56:19 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)}

console.log(currentTime == currentTime2);
// false
```

My question is why that 2 values currentTime and currentTime2 are not equal even their values "look" the same in Firefox console.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as minitech points out, milliseconds are stripped from the Date object's `toString` method, in order to be absolutely sure that the numeric value of `currentTime` equals that of `currentTime2`, you'll need to set the milliseconds of `currentTime2`:

```
currentTime2.setMilliseconds(currentTime % 1000);
```

Then, as cwolves points out, you can compare each `Date`'s `getTime` output. So when complete, it would look something like this:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentTimeInMill = Date.parse(currentTime);
var currentTime2 = new Date(currentTimeInMill);
currentTime2.setMilliseconds(currentTime % 1000);

// debug in firefox
console.log(currentTime);
// Date {Thu Jul 07 2011 09:56:19 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)}

console.log(currentTime2);
// Date {Thu Jul 07 2011 09:56:19 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)}

console.log(currentTime.getTime() == currentTime2.getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

You won't ever get two "Objects" in JavaScript to be equal using `==` unless they reference the ***exact same object***.  Javascript equality checks to see if they reference the same object before it checks to see if any values are similar.

Put simply, when comparing objects `==` is identical to `===`

Your check should be:

```
currentTime.getTime() == currentTime2.getTime();
// or
+currentTime == +currentTime2; // cast both to numbers and compare the numbers
```

Comment: Both the answers together are actually applicable here, actually. It's true that you need to compare the results of `getTime()` or `valueOf()` and not the objects themselves, but BeCool's code actually does result in two Date objects with different values, since `Date.parse` is only "seeing" the string representation; the sub-second precision is being discarded.

Comment: If you link to `underscore.js` you can use `_.isEqual(currentTime,currentTime2)` to check for equivalence.

Comment: @Lime - why use a library when my 2nd snip is actually shorter?

Comment: @cwolves It allows actually comparison of objects instead of converting them to `int`s.  People commonly run into the same issues later, and can't simply cast them to ints.  Later you can actually compare objects `_.isEqual({a:1},{a:1})` while this won't work `{a:1}=={a:1}`.  I'm just trying to kill 2 birds with one stone.

Comment: I look at their values again and realised they are actually different in million seconds (the last 3 digits) e.g. 1309999487252 vs 1309999487000
So i guess the Date.parse() function round up (ignore) the million second bit.
 So cwolves answers were close but not right.

Comment: @Lime - okay, it's valid for the 2nd example, I think it's overkill for dates though :)

Comment: @BeCool, see my answer. Essentially, there were two problems, and each of the previous answers addressed one but not the other. I combined the gist of both of the other answers and provided example code for how to solve both issues.

Answer (score 2):

It's because time strings aren't round-trip. If you try this:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentTimeInMill = Date.parse(currentTime);
var currentTime2 = new Date(currentTimeInMill);

console.log(currentTime.getTime());

console.log(currentTime2.getTime());

console.log(currentTime == currentTime2);
// false
```

You'll see that the times are different. `currentTime2` ends in 3 zeroes and `currentTime` has something else. It's a minute difference, in the milliseconds, which date strings obviously don't include.

Comment: @cwolves, it is and it isn't. What you say in your own answer about comparison of objects is correct, but what minitech says about the consequences of using `Date.parse` is also correct, making your own answer incorrect too. Comparing the `getTime()` return values has a 0.1% chance of giving the expected results (only if `currentTime` is instantiated at a time that is a multiple of 1000 ms).

Comment: Yeah, I tried to un-downvote you but can't unless you modify the answer :) -- edited and +1'd :)

Answer (score 0):

currentTime-currentTime2===0 is a quick way to test thet two dates refer to the same timestamp.